# Atomic doubles/floats in Intel TBB

Tags: c++, atomic, tbb

According to the documentation, an atomic supports T that is of an integral type,
enumeration type, or a pointer type. Does Intel TBB support floats/doubles officially?
I have seen some patches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242172/is-this-%20c-implementation-for-an-atomic-float-safe) and by Raf Schietekat [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=58680), which might/might not have been incorporated into the latest 4.0 release. From the patches I have read through, the only major difference I noticed was the addition of reinterpret_cast from integer type to float/double. If anyone could clarify this, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add support for floating-point numbers building on top of 64 and 32 bit atomic integers. Atomic load/store/exchange can be implemented as direct wrappers using reinterpret_cast, the atomic arithmetic operations can be implemented using a loop with atomic compare exchange.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 supports atomic floats and doubles. Arithmetic functions like `std::atomic_fetch_add` are only supported for integral types, though.

If you have a C++11 compiler, I would recommend to switch to `std::atomic` so you don't have to rely on undocumented behavior.

Comment: Also worth noting that the arithmetic functions can be easily and efficiently emulated with `std::atomic`.

Comment: Interesting. What is the best way to do it? Is it a compare-and-swap loop? (Fetch the current value and try to swap it with the new result. If it fails because the value was changed, retry.)

Answer (score 0):

The test for non-integral types in test_atomic.cpp was added back in 2008 (soon after the time of the discussion with Raf). Thus since even early than the time of the question, TBB supports float&double atomics (though restricted to fetch_and_store and compare_and_exchange read-modify-write ops only).